# d3.js albersUsa - where is the map data?

Tags: d3.js

I can't find where the map data is stored for the albersUsa projection (i.e. the state lines and the county lines etc.). And I can't find it in the d3 package. Where is this information stored?

I plan on doing something similar with other countries, and need to modify the state/county/country lines that it references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D3 doesn't come with any map data and neither do any of the projections. You have to get the GeoJSON somewhere else, e.g. [here](http://eric.clst.org/Stuff/USGeoJSON).